# Getting products count and products per page

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, pagination

I'm using this code getting products. And also using some addAttributeToFilter method for filter.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addStoreFilter()
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
    ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
```

Also I'm using `$collection->count()` code to get products count.

I'm trying to write my own pagination. (My products page is really complicated.)

Then I use this code `setPage($pageNumber, $productsPerPage)` to paginate.

But if I'm gonna paginate `$collection->count()` function return $productsPerPage number.

For example:

```
setPage(1, 6) // 6 product per page
$collection->count() // return 6 (but I have 16 products!)
```

If I use only `$collection->count()` code, it return 16!

What I'm missing?

I hope you guys understand me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$collection->count()` loads the collection and returns the number of products matching the select associated to the collection.
I think you are looking for `$collection->getSize()`. This will get you the total number of products matching the select, but ignores the limit.
Also `getSize` does not load the collection, so it's faster.